# How do I unpair my Bluetooth Headphones from my phone without access to my phone?

Tags: headphones

I've a complex problem.

My phone refuses to turn its screen on. Its touch screen has proven to still work, but it just simply refuses to open the screen.

I bought a new phone, but my problem consists of the fact that my wireless headphones are still paired up through bluetooth to the phone that wont open its screen anymore.

I dont remember how to navigate to the bluetooth screen in the settings with a black screen.

My problematic phone is an Allview P6 Qmax.
My headphones are a Panasonic RPBTD5K.

I would like to know if its possible to use... Maybe a third party program, thats capable of unpairing my problematic phone from my headphones.

Or if my headphones have a command to unpair from what they're paired with.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I've found that I can long press the power button on the headphones to unpair them from the phone. Thanks me.

Anyhow, if anyone here does know the answer to some third party program or some other solution to unpairing bluetooth devices from unresponsive phones, please comment for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

The headphones probably connect to the last device they were connected to. Just move your phone away a certain distance so that the headphones are out of reach for the bluetooth to connect. Then connect the headphones to a different device, to stop it from automatically connecting to your broken phone.